# Moving reporting logic into .NET code: Releasing fixes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting

At this moment, all of our reports are currently written in stored procedures.  We want to start moving this away from a SQL platform and rather to focus most of the logic in .NET code.  Reasons include the use of our ORM entities, ease of debugging, parallel processing, more unification with business logic, etc.

The problem we face is that by moving our report logic into .NET code, we cannot deploy support fixes as easily as running a script on our production environment.  Releasing binaries means that the whole business has to stop using our application, which is almost impossible during office hours.

One solution is to separate each report into a new project and release just that DLL.  The problem with this is that we have over 500 reports.  Maintaining that will be a nightmare.

Has anyone experienced something similar or have any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed as not constructive, but thanks to all for their replies!

Comment: I'm note sure either. @George please could comment as why you feel this off topic?

Comment: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Reporting Services? It is made for this! You can even train people in the business (non-devs) to create reports for you and publish them. There are so many features that users can just leverage. Authentication/Authorization, subscribe, export (PDF, Excel, Word), etc.

I wouldn't invest in rebuilding Reporting Services if I was you. I always stir away from writing reports as part of you application or in 'code'.

If you really, really want to do this (which I totally think you shouldn't do) then I would develop a separate service that generates reports (on a separate end-point) that you can call from your main application. Put a queue in the middle that stores 'report requests' when you need to update and the requests can be served after a restart.

Other option would be to go with dynamically loading assemblies. Let a filewatcher watch a folder and as soon as there is a new dll load it dynamically. Unloading is more difficult. You could restart the service when it is not so busy to get remove the old reports from memory or you need to create separate appdomains that you can unload.

A lot of options, but again, you will be wasting time by building and testing a custom report framework. I would go for plain SQL, even if you really like C#, this way you can hire a BI person that can just create reports instead of a dev.

Comment: We are not trying to migrate our "layout code" (that's a whole other topic - we are actually using Crystal Reports at the mo).  The problem lies purely with the logic involved with drawing the information for some of our reports (investment data which is very complex and very policy-bound).  Having this logic in tens of thousands of SQL statements over various functions/stored procs is absolutely awful.

Comment: Well that depends of course on what your expertise is. Not sure if a lot of slower C# code is better. Don't you have a BI/DB specialist writing and maintaining the SP's?
My opinion is that Crystal Reports is awful. On paper it is great, but in practice a hell! Although reporting services is simpler, I recommend this over Crystal Reports anytime.

Comment: We do have a BI team and most of our reports will stay as is and will be maintained by them, but we need a better solution for those reports which aren't suited to SQL.  Thanks a lot for your replies by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with a lot @bart's answer. My first reaction is that this seems like a unneeded reinvention.

However if you do need .net code and and convenience of declarative code, then why not use a DLR based language like iron python?

We've stored iron python in the db and loaded it on demand. Once jitted it's no different than any non dlr based code, deploying fixes was a dream.

Comment: I will look at your suggestion.  Another option I am looking at is CLR Integration.  Is this a similar concept? Thanks!